# convert query syntax to Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert the following query syntax into lambda expression.
I am trying to do that but don't know how can I use let clause inside lambda expression.

```
 List<ClInd> clIndls =
                   (from clIndls in Connection.ClIndls
                    join indls in Connection.Indls
                    on clIndls.IndID equals indls.ID
                    where pins.Contains(indls.PIN.Value)
                    let clIndal = clIndls.ClIndalAddes.OrderByDescending(y => y.UpdatedDate).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClIndID == clIndls.ID)
                    select new ClInd
                    {
                        ID = clIndls.ID,
                        MailingAddress = new LiableIndlAddress(){
                          City = clIndal.Address.City,
                        }
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

My approach:

```
            List<ClaimLiableIndividual> claimLiableIndividuals = Connection.ClIndls.Join(Connection.Indls,
                clIndls => clIndls.IndID,
                indls => indls.ID,
                (clmIndividuals, individuals) => new { ClmIndividuals = clmIndividuals, Individuals = individuals }).Where(x => pins.Contains(indls.PIN.Value))
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `let` is translated as a `.Select` call but you really shouldn't be doing this translation because the code you have right now is far more readable than the result will be when translated. Don't make clear code shitty

Comment: I need to write unit test for this method, I am using Moq.Expression, i am facing hard time to write unit test for a query syntax so I am converting it into lamda expression so that I can write unit test

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. The two syntaxes have equivalent semantics, producing expressions of the exact same type having the exact same meaning.

Comment: FYI It's called Method Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to be honest i'd avoid method syntax if it comes to `Join` and if you have already working code, i don't like the joins in method syntax. However...

There's no `let` in method syntax, you needed to put the result in a property of an anonymous type(or other type). But here you don't need it:

```
List<ClaimLiableIndividual> claimLiableIndividuals =
    Connection.ClIndls.Join(
        Connection.Indls,
        clIndls => clIndls.IndID,
        indls   => indls.ID,
        (clmIndividuals, individuals) => new 
        { 
            ClmIndividuals = clmIndividuals, 
            Individuals = individuals 
        }
    )
    .Where(x => pins.Contains(x.Individuals.PIN.Value))
    .Select(x => new ClInd
    {
        ID = x.ClmIndividuals.ID,
        MailingAddress = new LiableIndlAddress
        { 
            City = x.ClmIndividuals.ClIndalAddes
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.UpdatedDate)
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ClIndID == x.ClmIndividuals.ID)?.Address.City
        }
    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Note that the `Distinct` just works if you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `ClInd`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, yes this is what I am looking for, its an old code so trying to refactor it

Comment: @sajeshNambiar, it is not refactoring but demolition of the readability. Install Reshaper it can do that for you in one click.